# Why does CSS Blend mode get overridden by fullPage.js, a jquery plugin?

Tags: css, fullpage.js, mix-blend-mode

CSS Blend mode is "deactivated" when used inside fullPage's default containers, *section* and *slide*.

Creator Alvaro Trigo instructed me to use option `css3: false` to solve the problem, but it only works with *section* and not with *slide* and besides, it makes page rolling animation quite choppy.

He also advised me that this is not a fullpage issue, but rather a css one.

Here is a codepen illustrating the issue:

https://codepen.io/zerino/pen/MXRvbb

And here is the topics in fullPage´s issue forum:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3288

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin is not the problem, you can delete all `js` from your example and blend mode still doesn't work.

[According to the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode):

> The mix-blend-mode CSS property describes how an element's content should blend with the content of the **element's direct parent** and the element's background.

Blend mode interacts with element's direct parent only. You can test it by setting a background color for `.intermediary` like I did [in this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaGzpZ).

Comment: Well, actually it did blend with background after I deleted the js script.

Comment: Setting the bg to the `.intermediary` did the trick, but I still don't get why it does not blend with `body` bg when plugin is on.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't recreate your issue and the spec seems to be very specific.